# Alamofire 3.0を使用してJSONデータを取得する方法

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

現在，[No.1スクール講師陣による　世界一受けたいiPhoneアプリ開発の授業](http://gihyo.jp/book/2015/978-4-7741-7295-8)という書籍で，Swiftを学習しているのですが，Xcodeのバージョンアップに伴い，Swift2.0に書き直してみようと思いましたが，解決が難しい箇所に直面しましたので，こちらで質問させていただきました．本来なら本家のサポートサイトの更新もしくは，Swift2.0対応版を待つべきところかと思いますが，ご回答いただけますと幸いです．

エラーが出ているファイル：
[サポートサイト](http://gihyo.jp/book/2015/978-4-7741-7295-8/support)からダウンロードしたファイル（Xcode 6.3+iOS8.3対応）->Chapter8->完成例->NewsReader->NewsReader->ViewController.swift
上記のファイルを「Latest Swift Syntax」にConvertしています．また，Alamofireは最新版をダウンロードし，追加しています．

エラー部分（override func viewDidLoad()内，35行目付近）：

```
Alamofire.request(.GET,requestUrl).responseJSON {(request, response, json, error) in
    let jsonDic = json as! NSDictionary
    let responseData = jsonDic["responseData"] as! NSDictionary
    self.newsDataArray = responseData["results"] as! NSArray
    self.table.reloadData()
}
```

上記の，

```
Alamofire.request(.GET,requestUrl).responseJSON {(request, response, json, error) in
```

という部分に

```
'(_, _, _, _) -> Void' is not convertible to 'Response<AnyObject, NSError> -> Void'
```

というエラーが表示されている状態です．

よろしくお願いいたします．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

これはAlamofireのAPI変更が原因です。

`responseJSON`の`completionHandler`のクロージャの型が`Response<AnyObject, NSError> -> Void`（いわゆるEither的なもの）に変更されました。

元のソースコードが特に異常系について考慮していないので、その前提で同様のコードを記述すると以下の通りです。

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, requestUrl).responseJSON {
    response in
    if response.result.isSuccess {
        //まずJSONデータをNSDictionary型に
        let jsonDic = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
        //辞書化したjsonDicからキー値"responseData"を取り出す
        let responseData = jsonDic["responseData"] as! NSDictionary
        //responseDataからキー値"results"を取り出す
        self.newsDataArray = responseData["results"] as! NSArray
        //ニュース記事を取得したらテーブルビューに表示
        self.table.reloadData()
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift2.0版AlamofireのresponseJSONは[クロージャの引数が public struct Responseになっているため](https://github.com/easyui/Alamofire/blob/1108ae4461baa99d9c4898c213ec3e2e2956fab3/Source/ResponseSerialization.swift#L267-L269)、以前の記述であった

```
(request, response, json, error) in
```

を

```
response in
```

のようにすれば良いです。ただし、このresponseは先述したように型が 'public struct Response' であり 'NSHTTPURLResponse'ではありませんので、手っ取り早く結果だけ欲しいのであれば次のようにResponseのresult.valueを使います。

```
Alamofire.request(.GET,requestUrl).responseJSON { response in
    if let jsonDic = response.result.value as? NSDictionary {
        let responseData = jsonDic["responseData"] as! NSDictionary
        self.newsDataArray = responseData["results"] as! NSArray
        self.table.reloadData()
    }
}
```

また、通信が成功したか失敗したかを判定し、エラーハンドリングしたいなどの場合は次のようにresultで判定するのが良いかもしれません。

```
Alamofire.request(.GET,requestUrl).responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .Success(let value):
        if let jsonDic = value as? NSDictionary {
            let responseData = jsonDic["responseData"] as! NSDictionary
            self.newsDataArray = responseData["results"] as! NSArray
            self.table.reloadData()                    
        }
    case .Failure(let error):
        // 通信のエラーハンドリングしたいなら
        print(error)
    }
}
```